# Sum of open ,closed neither open and closed sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let A and B be subsets of $R^n$ Define

$A+B=\{a+b\ |\ a\in\, A , b\in \,B\}$

Consider the sets 
 $W=\{(x,y) \in\,R^2\ |\ x>0 , y>0\}
\\ X=\{(x,y) \in\,R^2\ |\ x\in\,R , y=0\}
\\ Y=\{(x,y) \in\,R^2\ |\ xy=1\}
\\Z=\{(x,y) \in\,R^2\ |\ |x|\le 1,|y|\le 1\}$
Which of the following statements are true

1. The Set $W+X$ is open
2. The Set $X+Y$ is closed
3. The Set $Y+Z$ is closed

Try I sincerely don't know how to proceed The answer is 1 and 3 I do know that sum of two open set is open in $R^n$ but that doesn't work over here

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few hints for each one.

$(1)$ Observe that $A$ is open (Why?), that the translation of any open set is open (Why?), and 
$$ W+X=\bigcup_{x\in X}(W+x). $$

$(2)$ Find a sequence in $X+Y$ convergent in $\mathbb{R}^2$, that does not converge in $X+Y$.

$(3)$  Observe that $Z$ is compact (Heine-Borel), and $Y$ is closed (Why?).  Try to show that the sum of a closed and a compact set is closed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Prove that $W+X=\{(x,y):y>0\}.$
2. For positive integer $n$ let $p_n=(-n,0)\in X$ and $q_n=(n,1/n)\in Y.$ Then $p_n+q_n=(0,1/n)$ which converges to $(0,0)$ as $n\to \infty.$ But $(0,0)\not \in X+Y$ because if $a=(x_1,0)\in X$ and $b=(x_2,1/x_2)\in Y$ then the second co-ordinate of $a+b$ is $1/x_2 ,$ which can't be $0.$
3. A sequence $(z_n)_n$  in $Z$ has a subsequence $(z'_n)_n$ that converges to a member of $Z.$

   $\quad$   So if $(y_n)_n$ is a sequence in $Y$ and $(z_n)_n$ is a sequence in $Z,$ such that $(y_n+z_n)_n$ converges to $p$, there is a subsequence $(y'_n+z'_n)_n,$ with $y'_n\in Y$ and $z'_n\in Z,$ such that $(z'_n)_n$ converges to  $z\in Z.$

   $\quad$ Now $(y'_n+z'_n-p)$  and $(z-z'_n)$ both converge to $0$ as $n\to \infty,$ so their sum  also does. Their sum is $y'_n-(p-z).$ So $y'_n$ converges to $p-z.$

   $\quad Y$ is closed, so  $p-z\in Y.$ Hence, with $p-z\in Y$ and $z\in Z$, we have $p=(p-z)+z\in Y+Z.$

Remark. There are examples of two unbounded closed subsets in $\mathbb R^2$ (even in $\mathbb R$) whose sum is not closed....  Let $A=\mathbb N$ and $B=\{-n-\frac {1}{n+1}:n\in \mathbb N\}.$ So $\{-\frac {1}{n+1}:n \in \mathbb N\}\subset A+B$ but $0\not \in A+B.$....In $\mathbb R^2,$ take $A\times \{0\}$ and $B\times \{0\}.$